# OpenGL ES API with no current context error

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

It seems that I am having a slight problem with Opengl ES 2. The program I have created displays a square that moves in one direction. I have done this before perfectly. It's just I have put a gameloop in it and now I am in a bit of a pickle. I am hoping someone can help me with the issue I am experiencing. (I have looked around for more then 3 days and cant figure it out).

**What I believe to be wrong but don't know how to fix:** Previously in the GameState Class, in the hitIt method. I had **playerModel.setPosition(xV, yV);** as **playerAssets.setPosition(xV, yV);**. As what was wrong with it before. The playerMode was Extended to PlayerModel. I was calling a class method directly when it was extended. After fixing that. I am now with my current problem (Call to OpengGL ES API with no current context).

**Note:** I had no error messages before I have changed it.

Activity

```
package com.Skit.main;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class DaSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView{

private DaRenderer daRend;

public DaSurfaceView(Context context, GamePhysics gamephy) {
    super(context);

    setEGLContextClientVersion(2); //Request OpenGL ES 2.0

    daRend = new DaRenderer(gamephy, this);
    setRenderer(daRend);

    //setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    return daRend.onTouchEvent(e);
   }
}
```

SurfaceView

```
package com.Skit.main;

import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class DaSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView{

private DaRenderer daRend;

public DaSurfaceView(Context context, GamePhysics gamephy) {
    super(context);

    setEGLContextClientVersion(2); //Request OpenGL ES 2.0

    daRend = new DaRenderer(gamephy, this);
    setRenderer(daRend);

    //setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    return daRend.onTouchEvent(e);
    }
}
```

Renderer

```
package com.Skit.main;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

public class DaRenderer implements Renderer{

static final float mProjectionMatrix[] = new float[16];

private PlayerModel playermodel;
private GamePhysics mgamephysics;
private DaSurfaceView surfview;


public DaRenderer(GamePhysics gamephy, DaSurfaceView surf){
    mgamephysics = gamephy;
    surfview = surf;

}

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
    GamePhysics gamephysics = mgamephysics;

    // Set the background color.
    GLES20.glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    gamephysics.setAssets();

    playermodel = new PlayerModel();
}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
    GamePhysics gamephysics = mgamephysics;

    gamephysics.hitIt();

    // Redraw background color
    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    gamephysics.playerDraw();
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    float ratio = (float) width / height;

    // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
    // in the onDrawFrame() method
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 2, 7);

}

public static int loadShader(int glVertexShader, String vertexShaderCode) {
     // create a vertex shader type (GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
    // or a fragment shader type (GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(glVertexShader);

    // add the source code to the shader and compile it
    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, vertexShaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
    }
}
```

GameState

```
package com.Skit.main;

import android.util.Log;

public class GamePhysics {
PlayerMode playerAssets = new PlayerMode();
PlayerModel playerModel = new PlayerModel();

//2D Cords & physics variables
private float xV, yV, v = 0.2f, t = 0.1f;

private int TT = 0;

public void setAssets(){
    xV = playerAssets.getXPosition();
    Log.d("GamePhysics", "XV = " + String.valueOf(xV));

    yV = playerAssets.getYPosition();
    Log.d("GamePhysics", "YV = " + String.valueOf(yV));
}

void playerDraw(){
    playerModel.draw();
}

void hitIt(){   
    xV = xV + 1;
    yV = yV;

    //PlayerAsset = PlayerMode.java
    playerModel.setPosition(xV, yV);
    Log.d("GamePhysics", String.valueOf(xV));
    }
}
```

PlayerMode

```
package com.Skit.main;

import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.util.Log;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;

public class PlayerMode {

protected float[] mModelView;

protected PlayerMode(){
    mModelView = new float[16];
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelView, 0);
}

public float getXPosition(){
    return mModelView[12];
}

public float getYPosition(){
    return mModelView[13];
}

public void setPosition(float x, float y){
    mModelView[12] = x;
    mModelView[13] = y;
    Log.d("PlayerMode", String.valueOf(mModelView[12]));
    }
}
```

PlayerModel

```
package com.Skit.main;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;

import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.Matrix;
import android.util.Log;

import com.Skit.main.DaRenderer;

public class PlayerModel extends PlayerMode {
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
private ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;

private static int mProgram;

private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;

private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

static final float mViewMatrix[] = new float[16];
static final float mMVPMatrix[] = new float[16];
static float mTempMVP[] = new float[16];

private final int vertexCount = triangleCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex



//Object Shaders
private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" + 
        "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
        "void main() {" +
        "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
        "}";

// number of coordinates per vertex in this array
static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
static float triangleCoords[] = {   // in counterclockwise order:
    -0.2f,  0.2f, 0.0f,   // top left
    -0.2f, -0.2f, 0.0f,   // bottom left
     0.2f, -0.2f, 0.0f,   // bottom right
     0.2f,  0.2f, 0.0f }; // top right

// Set color with red, green, blue and alpha (opacity) values
float color[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
private short[] drawOrder = { 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3 };     

public PlayerModel() {
    // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            // (number of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
            triangleCoords.length * 4);
    // use the device hardware's native byte order
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

    // create a floating point buffer from the ByteBuffer
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    // add the coordinates to the FloatBuffer
    vertexBuffer.put(triangleCoords);
    // set the buffer to read the first coordinate
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
    // (# of coordinate values * 2 bytes per short)
            drawOrder.length * 2);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer.put(drawOrder);
    drawListBuffer.position(0);

    int vertexShader = DaRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
            vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = DaRenderer.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
            fragmentShaderCode);

    // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();

    // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);

    // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);

    // creates OpenGL ES program executables
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);
}

public void draw() {

    float[] mvp = mTempMVP;

    // Add program to OpenGL ES environment
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -3, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // combine the projection and camera view Matrix
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, DaRenderer.mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

    // Combine the Projection/Camera view with ModelView
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mvp, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mModelView, 0);

    //Log to see if modelview is being passed from playermode
    Log.d("PlayerModel", String.valueOf(mModelView[12]));

    //pass the projection and view transformation to the shader
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvp, 0);

    //get handle to shape's transformation matrix
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");

    // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

    // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

    // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                                 GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                 vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

    // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

    // Set color for drawing the triangle
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

    // Draw the triangle
    GLES20.glDrawElements(
            GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, drawOrder.length,
            GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer);

    // Disable vertex array
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    }   
}
```

---

I am fairly new to all of this. Sorry for the sloppy code.

Comment: I think the issue might be in the gamePhysics class but it could be anything.

Comment: You need to say more about what the problem is and what you've tried. All you've given us so far is an error message (in the subject) and a whole lot of code. Identify where it's failing and under what circumstances.

Comment: My bad. Previously in the GameState class in the hitIt method. I had **playerModel.setPosition(xV, yV);** as **playerAssets.setPosition(xV, yV);**. and When I had playerAssets it would display the box but the variable from playerMode (float[] mModelView) would not extend to the playerModel class. but after I have changed it, the mModelView variable is extended to playerModel but now I am getting my current error message.

Comment: Check which thread is creating the GLES context, and which thread is making the call that's failing. One way to get this error is to make the call on the wrong thread. (You can just send a message to the log file if you've configured it to show thread IDs, e.g. `adb logcat -v threadtime`.)

Comment: I have found my issue for now. The issue was in my Renderer class **(onSurfaceCreated method)**. I din't know you needed to allocate my playerModel class in Gamephysics **(made a new method: gamephysics.allocPlayer)**. Thank you so much that has helped alot. But now I'm having a slight issue with the block not showing. BUT! I din't ask that question. thats my issue. Thank you again.